# Nombre dinámico a valor json javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy aprendiendo javascript, y estoy viendo como trabajar con valores json, y ahora que estoy practicando estoy teniendo problemas, el problema se presenta con el siguiente código:

```js
      miJson = {}
     
var name = "nombre"
var answer = "Texto"

miJson.name = answer
console.log(miJson)
```

(Los valores de las variables `name` y `answer` no son fijos como los muestro, los valores los obtengo de otra forma pero la idea es la misma) Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer que la "llave" que se agrege al json sea el valor de la variable `name`? Y que el `console.log` me muestre esto:

```
}
  "nombre": "Texto"
}
```

Desde ya gracias :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```javascript
var miJson = {}
     
var name = "nombre"
var answer = "Texto"

miJson[name] = answer
console.log(miJson)
```

poniendo `[name]` se evalua el valor de `name`. Entonces este valor se guarda como una propiedad del objeto.

Te dejo este [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#notaci%C3%B3n_de_corchetes%5D) con mas informacion basica acerca de los objetos en javascript.

Comment: Muchas gracias, como dijiste ya funcionó :).